# Почему tkinter.Text.image_create заполняет прозрачный background?

Tags: python, tkinter, photoimage

В моём приложении я загружаю картинки с прозрачным фоном "".png (пробовал и .jpg) с помощью

```
image = requests.get(url)
with open(filename, 'wb') as file:
    file.write(image.content)
```

в проводнике всё  отображается нормально:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но как только я вставляю изображение в Текстовый виджет tkinter.Text методом

```
image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(filename))
self.text_field.image_create('end', image=image)
```

Прозрачный фон становится непрозрачным:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ранее, у меня работало всё так, как я хотел, но после того, как я переустановил python 3.7, у меня возникла такая проблема.

Comment: Попробуйте использовать Canvas, там поддерживается прозрачность и можно вставить текст.

Comment: Изображение было сохранено как «RGBA», то есть RGB с альфа-каналом?

Comment: Сергей Кох, насчет "RGBA" изображений не знаю, я их сохранял как описал выше. Если знаете как это сделать подскажите или дайте источник какой-нибудь. Попробую Canvas.